# Give three functions for which exactly two out of three assumptions of Rolle’s theorem are satisﬁed but for which the conclusion does not follow.

Tags: real-analysis

The first function chosen is easy to fall into: just pick one that a does not equal b; such as $\frac{1}{x},\; x>0$. It is continuous and differentiable.

For the next I restrict a function $f(x) = x^{2}\;, x<0$,  and $f(x) = -x^{2}\;, x \ge 0$  and $f(0) = 0$  so it would seem that it's differentiable on $(a,b)$ and we can suppose there is an $a = b$ with a horizontal line  so that this exception is a lack of continuity.

I'm probably wrong on these, but if I'm going in the right direction, now I'm left with needing a function where f(a)=f(b) and it is continuous on $[a,b]$, but that there is no $f'(c) = 0$.

Comment: Perhaps you should state the three assumptions in the order in which they were stated in the course.

Comment: You apparently write $a = b$ for $f(a) = f(b)$.

Comment: f is continuous on [a,b]; f is differentiable on (a,b); f(a)=f(b)

Comment: This should be part of the question.

Comment: Also, please explain which two assumptions are satisfied for each of your examples.

Comment: Those are the given assumptions of Rolle's Theorem.   Never the less, there they are.....

Comment: I did explain. First one: is continuous and differentiable, but f(a) does not = f(b)  Second one: f(a) = f(b) and is differentiable on (a,b), but the defined function lacks continuity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)=|x|$, on the interval $[-1,1]$. The function is continuous and $f(1)=f(-1)$. However, there is no $c\in (-1,1)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

Comment: I already suggested that, but apparently this is not what the OP is interested in. I suggest you wait for the question to receive its definitive form.

Comment: @azarel   does not being differentiable @ 0 make it fit the definition of "not differentiable on (a,b)?

Comment: thanks azarel....I forgot about the final result: that the f'(c) needed to be zero...not at all whether or not is differentiable

Answer (score 0):

Your second function doesn't work since a function which is differentiable at a neighborhood of $x$ is also continuous there. You want a function which is differentiable (and so continuous) inside $(a,b)$ but only continuous at the endpoints (or at least one of them).

For your third function, take a look at the absolute value function. It is continuous but not differentiable, and where you'd expect the zero derivative, at the minimum $x = 0$, the function is unfortunately not differentiable.

Comment: if f(x) = abs(x), I get derivative value of 1...(x over abs x = 1)...continuous on [a,b] and f(a)=f(b) but cannot be differentiated...what am I missing regarding abs value idea?